# Finding MBUS telegramms in an byte[]

Tags: c#, .net, byte, arrays

I'm trying to read MBUS telegramms from a serial port. 
I put everything from the serialport into an byte array.

Every MBUS telegramms starts with this pattern (in hex):   68 XX XX 68
where XX is the lenght of the telegramm in byte.

Example:
[Example http://img97.imageshack.us/img97/6004/mbustele.jpg](http://img97.imageshack.us/img97/6004/mbustele.jpg)

Here you see an example, highlighted is the beginning of an telegramm with lenght 99 (in hex)

I want to add every telegramm to a list like this

```
List<byte[]> telegramms;
```

An idea how to achieve this?

Comment: You want to search the byte[] from the serial port for these data packets and then save a list of what you find ?

Comment: Yes, in my example i want to be 68 99 99 68 and the following 99 bytes (in hex) to be the first entry of my List...   and so on.

Comment: Not quite, 99 is 153 in decimal, also its a double byte 9999, which means 39321 bytes of data.

Comment: Similarly, I don't know which 'endian' order this data is in, I'm going to go with the the BitConverter which is Little Endian, but you'll need to find out from the MBus specification what the byte order is.

Comment: In this case 99(hex) stands for 153 Bytes

Comment: If someone else is looking for MBUS specs:
You can find it hre:
http://www.m-bus.com/mbusdoc/default.php

Comment: Yes, but its not 99, its 9999, which is 39321 bytes. I'm just writing some demo code that should get you started.

Comment: I just checked MBUs specs again and it's supposed to be 99.
The lenght is transmitted twice to be verified. 
I would be very glad for some demo code :)
thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's variable, but yes - it should only be counted as a single byte albeit hexadecimal, I've updated my test to accommodate this fact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my attempt, what do you think?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace MBUS_Parse_Test.MDL64_Communication
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Extracts MBUS telegramms
    /// </summary>
    class GetMBUS_Telegramms
    {
    #region Eigenschaften
    private static List<MbusTelegram> telegrams = new List<MbusTelegram>();
    #endregion

    public static List<MbusTelegram> GetTelegramms(byte[] logfile)
    {
        int startOfTele = ExtractFirstMBUSTelegramm(logfile);
        while (startOfTele != 0)
        {
            byte[] NewLogFile = new byte[logfile.Length - startOfTele];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(logfile, startOfTele, NewLogFile, 0, NewLogFile.Length);
            startOfTele = ExtractFirstMBUSTelegramm(NewLogFile);
            logfile = NewLogFile;
        }
        return telegrams;
    }

    private static int ExtractFirstMBUSTelegramm(byte[] logfile)
    {
        byte mbus_start = 0x68;
        int Start = Array.IndexOf(logfile, mbus_start);
        int offset = 10;
        if (logfile[Start + 3] == mbus_start)
        {
            byte[] newMBUS = new byte[logfile[Start + 1] + offset];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(logfile, Start, newMBUS, 0, logfile[Start + 1] + offset);
            MbusTelegram nuMBUS = new MbusTelegram(newMBUS);
            telegrams.Add(nuMBUS);
            return (Start + logfile[Start + 1] + offset);
        }
        return 0;
    }

    private System.Array ResizeArray(System.Array oldArray, int newSize)
    {
        int oldSize = oldArray.Length;
        System.Type elementType = oldArray.GetType().GetElementType();
        System.Array newArray = System.Array.CreateInstance(elementType, newSize);
        int preserveLength = System.Math.Min(oldSize, newSize);
        if (preserveLength > 0)
            System.Array.Copy(oldArray, newArray, preserveLength);
        return newArray;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In this I already use a MbusTelegram Class which mainly contains the byte array...

Comment: Datagram. You have searched for opc foundation and opc servers? Which, some of them, are free and built to parse and analyze pakets for identification. Out from OPC you get meter specifikations and measured values.

Answer (score 1):

I've just typed this up in VisualStudio 2010, it makes all sorts of assumptions about endian-ness and does't managed the potential problem of the MBus packet being bigger that the sampled byte from the serial port, or more importantly, if the packet *header* itself is across the boundary between packets from the serial port.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace StackOverflowTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class ByteTest
    {
        private bool FindEndMark(byte[] source, int index, out int size)
        {
            int endIndex = index + 3;
            if (endIndex > source.Count())
            {
                // need to cope with the fact that the datapacket might be shorter than the MBus message.
                throw new Exception("end count > length of array");
            }

        if (source[endIndex] == 0x68)
        {
            // According to the updated spec, the size is emitted twice as a verification
            if (source[index + 1] == source[index + 2])
            {
                size = source[index] + 1;
                return true;
            }
        }
            size = 0;
            return false;
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void FindMbusDatagram()
        {
            byte[] src = new byte[]
                {
                    // Random junk to start
                    00, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 0xa, 0xb, 0xc, 0xd, 
                    // An MBus Packet
                    0x68, 06, 00, 0x68, 08, 05, 72, 00, 00, 00, 
                    // More junk
                    00, 00, 00, 0x16, 00, 00, 00, 00, 01, 
                    // Put a rogue 0x68 in so we can prove we don't get false positives in the datastream
                    0x68, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 0xa, 0xb, 0xc, 0xd,
                    // Another Packet
                    0x68, 01, 00, 0x68, 0xFF,
                    //final junk
                     00, 16, 00, 00, 00, 01, 02, 03
                };

            List<byte[]> packets = new List<byte[]>();

            for (int i = 0; i < src.Length; i++ )
            {
                if (src[i] != 0x68)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    int packetSize = 0;
                    if (FindEndMark(src, i, out packetSize))
                    {
                        if (packetSize > (src.Length - i))
                        {
                            // read more data from your port and append it somehow.
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // We're packetSize+4 includes the header information + checksum and end
                        // NB: packetSize+5 is a checksum byte
                        // NB: packetSize+6 should be 0x16 according to the MBus spec.
                            byte[] packet = new byte[packetSize + 4];
                            int count = 0;

                            // Copy the packet + header into a byte[]
                            for (int j = i; j < (i + packetSize + 4); j++)
                            {
                                packet[count++] = src[j];
                            }

                            packets.Add(packet);

                            // Move the counter along
                            i += (packetSize + 4);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // Should have two packets here.
            Assert.IsTrue(packets.Count > 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code makes the assumption that the 68 LL LL 68 is a double byte however. This PDF about MBus seems to indicate that length is variable:  http://www.sensusesaap.com/files/MBUS_RSP_UD_PSE-EE-WE-V2.pdf

Comment: I've updated the code to include the updated detail about the packet size, and some extra data about the checksum byte.

Comment: How are you getting on with this ?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have tested your code and it works pretty code, but for some reason every packet contains a few bytes to much. I'm still looking for the reason...

Comment: In the code above, it records the header 4 bytes, also I think the specification says that after length bytes, there is more data including a checksum and an end byte of 0x16